# Flutter: Difference if using await

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

Imagine im calling an `async` function with return type `Future<void>` called `_uploadData` inside the `onPressed` property of a `Button`, and the UI does not depend on the function call.

**1st**

```
onPressed: () async {
    await _uploadData();
},
```

**or 2nd**

```
onPressed: () {
    _uploadData();
}
```

Does it make any difference? And if it doesn't, is the 1st one just the better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, these codes have different behavior. if you use async/await syntax the code will not continue and will wait until the future completes its work. so If your UI does not depend on Future don't use async/await. otherwise use it. if you want to understand it open [the dart-pad counter sample](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) and add below code to it.

```
  void _incrementCounter() async{
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

convert _incrementCounter() method to above code.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's really clear to me. Another interesting thing: wrap your code inside incrementCounter with a loop which executes e.g.  5 times and then execute the code with the await keyword in front of the Future.delayed and then without, this would demonstrate a series of async calls where you just have to make sure every call is executed as fast as possible, without waiting for each other.